# ¿Cómo puedo llamar un SDK de un tercero a mí proyecto?

Tags: c#, sdk

Quizás sea sencillo.

El sistema es AdminPaq y ContPaqi Factura Electrónica.

NO he trabajado con SDKs con C#, solo en Android Studio.

Tengo el SDK y los DLLS que se deben de utilizar.

La documentación me dice lo siguiente:
donde MGW_SDK es un dll que es la interfaz de comunicación.

```
Establecer el directorio del MGW_SDK  
Inicializar SDK  
   Abrir Empresa  
     Tu función o proceso completo  
   Cerrar Empresa  
Terminar SDK
```

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
int error;
        string regsystem = @"\\directorio\carpeta1\carpetafinal";

        error = AdminpaqSdk.fSetNombrePAQ("AdminPAQ");
        error = AdminpaqSdk.fInicializaSDK(); 
      if(error != 0)
      {

      }
```

Pero esto me dice:

```
   Se intentó cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto. (Excepción de 
  HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Saludos.

Comment: de que SDK hablas?, tienes algun ejemplo de que es lo que trataste de hacer?

Comment: La sdk es de un sistema contable para Mexico llamado AdminPaq, pero dicho sistema utiliza una DB ne Foxpro, dicho sdk segun la documentacion se tiene que usar afuerza dicho servicion para seguir las reglas de negocion, entonces tenqo que usar afuerza dicho SDK para mandarle datos a la DB de ellos, tengo el formulario con los datos que le voy a enviar, pero no tengo idea de como interactuar con ese SDK.

Comment: Provee el sdk y veremos si se te puede ayudar

Comment: ¡Hola! Honestamente, yo creo que no es buenas prácticas llamar ejecutables desde .NET, pero si no tienes alternativas creo que este artículo te puedes ser útil: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ilMattion no es llamar un ejecutable, son archivos dlls que el proveedor de sistema otorga para que desarrolladores teceros puedan utilizar su base de datos siempre y cuando se respeten las reglas del negocio. Se entiende eso en la pregunta, la voy a editar.

Comment: Al ser una dll tan específica y rebuscada te recomiendo que te contactes con el soporte del desarrollador de esa librería. A no ser que alguien justo se haya topado con tu problema o entienda mejor las cosas acá

Answer (score -1):

Con respecto a establecer el directorio del CompaqI en este caso "Comercial" pero puede ser "AdminPaq" e inicializar el SDK puedes ocupar esta función con estas constantes.

Para AdminPaq
        public const string NombreLlaveRegistroAdminpaq = @"SOFTWARE\Computación en Acción, SA CV\AdminPAQ";
        public const string NombrePaqAdminpaq = "AdminPAQ";

```
    public static int InicializarSDK()
    {
        var keySistema = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(NombreLlaveRegistroAdminpaq);
        var lEntrada = keySistema.GetValue("DirectorioBase");
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(lEntrada.ToString());
        return AdminpaqSdk.fSetNombrePAQ(NombrePaqAdminpaq);
    }
```

Fin de AdminPaq

Para Comercial

```
    public const string NombreLlaveRegistroComercial = @"SOFTWARE\\Computación en Acción, SA CV\\CONTPAQ I COMERCIAL";
    public const string NombrePaqComercial = "CONTPAQ I COMERCIAL";

    public static int InicializarSDK()
    {
        var keySistema = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(NombreLlaveRegistroComercial);
        var lEntrada = keySistema.GetValue("DirectorioBase");
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(lEntrada.ToString());
        return ComercialSdk.fSetNombrePAQ(NombrePaqComercial);
    }
```

Fin de Comercial

Al momento de inicializar el SDK te pedirá Login y password. Despues puedes estar invocando funciones del SDK sin problema, como puede ser :

iError = Contpaqi.Sdk.ComercialSdk.fPosPrimerEmpresa(ref id, nombre, ruta);
ó
iError = Contpaqi.Sdk.ComercialSdk.fAbreEmpresa(empresasList[0].Ruta);

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Hola @CarlosPonton, bienvenido!! Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y comentes un poco de que modo estás solucionando el problema, para que la persona que pregunta pueda entenderla mejor. Además, con esto evitas que te eliminen la respuesta por baja calidad. Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)